# How do I use a method defined in another class, without a calling object?

Tags: java

I'm new at Java and I'm trying to call a get method from a different public class. The code processes but 'answer' returns "WineTempTime$Winechiller@45ee12a7" for some reason I can't figure out.

Is there an issue in my method definition or is it a problem with the method constructor? Grateful for help!

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WineTempTime {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   // code that inputs double wineTemp, preferedTemp, chillTemp here

        Winechiller answer = new Winechiller();
        answer.getChillingtime(wineTemp, preferedTemp, chillTemp);

        System.out.print("It takes " + answer + " minutes for wine to 
reach desired temperature.");
    }   
}

public static class Winechiller {

// constructors
static final double DELTA_MINUTES = 0.1;
static final int TAO = 50;
WineTempTime wineTemp = new WineTempTime();
WineTempTime preferedTemp = new WineTempTime();
WineTempTime chillTemp = new WineTempTime();
double timeCount = 0;

// equation for minutes until reaches temperature 
public int getChillingtime(double wineTemp, double preferedTemp, double 
chillTemp) {
    while (wineTemp > preferedTemp) {
        double tempDecrease = ( (wineTemp - chillTemp) / TAO ) 
        * DELTA_MINUTES;
        wineTemp -= tempDecrease;
        ++timeCount; }
    timeCount /= 10;
    Math.round(timeCount);
    int minutes = (int)timeCount;
    return minutes;     
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that question, the OP doesn't know that she should assign the result of the method to a variable to print it - she wants to print an integer, not the `answer` object!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you code you have printed the `answer` directly Don't print it directly .

print as

```
 System.out.print("It takes " + answer.getChillingtime(wineTemp, preferedTemp, 
    chillTemp) + " minutes for wine to reach desired temperature.");
```

and you called the function `getChillingtime()` without storing it Because it returns an integer.
so you exclude the line

```
 answer.getChillingtime(wineTemp, preferedTemp, chillTemp);
```

In your program you printed `answer` As `answer` is an object of `Winechiller` class ,So while you try to print `answer` you will get the information of the answer object because the statement

```
System.out.println(answer);
```

gets converted to form

```
 System.out.println(answer.toString());
```

where `toString()` is the method of Object class which is the super of all java classes.

Answer (score 1):

You should print out the result of the method `answer.getChillingtime`, instead of `answer`.

```
int minutes = answer.getChillingtime(wineTemp, preferedTemp, chillTemp);
System.out.print("It takes " + minutes + " minutes for wine to reach desired temperature.");
```